# AspectJ, multi-module maven interdeterminate failures

Tags: maven, aspectj, tycho

We have a multi-module project based on maven (tycho to be exact), using aspectj.

We are encountering a strange problem where if we build each module separately, no problems appear.

When trying to build all the modules together we have random failures (not necessarily in the same module every time) where the build fails usually with the message "can't determine modifiers of missing type...". Sometimes even, if we repeat the build many times we might even get a lucky and get no errors.

Does anybody have any idea what the problem might be?

---

We are using version 1.8 of the aspectj-maven-plugin and 1.8.9 of aspectj

Our project structure is the following:

```
parentpom.xml
    ---------> moduleA
    ---------> moduleAspect
    ---------> moduleB
    ---------> moduleC
```

*ModuleA* is in the *Inpath* of *moduleAspect*

*moduleB* and *ModuleC* have in their *AspectPath* *moduleAspect*

This is an example of an aspect in *moduleAspect*. (Class *Incoming* is defined in *moduleA*)

```
public aspect SecurityAspect {
   public interface Security {
       String getRole();
   }
   declare parents:  Incoming extends  IncomingSecurity;
   public String IncomingImpl.getRole() {
       return getEditor();
   };
   pointcut privilegedAccess(Incoming inc):
     //;
   before(Incoming inc): privilegedAccess(inc){
       //;
   }
```

}

This is the *pom.xml* in *moduleAspect*

```
<artifactId>moduleAspect</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <weaveDependencies>
                    <weaveDependency>
                        <groupId>myproject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
                    </weaveDependency>                      
                </weaveDependencies>
                <aspectDirectory>src</aspectDirectory>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>weave-classes</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And this is what the pom looks like in moduleC.

```
<artifactId>moduleC</artifactId>
<parent>
    <groupId>myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>myProject</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduleAspect</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <XaddSerialVersionUID>true</XaddSerialVersionUID>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <aspectDirectory>src</aspectDirectory>

                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>myProject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>moduleAspect</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>                    
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile_with_aspectj</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>                
            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: is this an RCP Application?

Comment: It has a RAP component, yes (module C to be exact is RAP based)

Comment: i don't know how you configured your Tycho Plugin but dependencies for Module C should go to the MANIFEST.MF file and be part of your Tycho Targetplatform

Comment: The project builts ok with tycho and in Eclipse, when aspectj is not used and in this case yes you are right we do not need to put the dependencies. If I use though the maven-aspectj-plugin in moduleC and I do not (re)declare the dependency to moduleAspect as I do, then the aspectj plugin complaints: "The artifact modelAspect referenced in aspectj plugin as an aspect library, is not found the project dependencies"

Comment: I would also like to point out that when the build fails, the error message refer to classes where weaving is not necessary.

Comment: Would you mind preparing a little [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and publishing it on GitHub? This is too complex in order to guess just seeing the POMs. But maybe there is an issue with the classes from module A being in the target directory of both A and aspect module B. I can only speculate. BTW, I know a lot about AspectJ itself and am quite familiar with AspectJ Maven, but have no experience with Tycho.